# How to start react app on custom port with CRACO?

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css, craco

I want to use Tailwind CSS for my react apps. The problem is `CRACO start` starts the app on the default port, which is 3000 and I want to have custom ports but I can't figure out what is the right approach. ( Can't find anything about this in their documentation )

I tried something like `PORT=5000 CRACO start` inside the `scripts` field of the `package.json` file but doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRACO use the webpack devserver configuration to set the port.

you need to create a configuration. read more here in the readme:

https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file

So you solution need to redefine `devServer`. How to define it read in the webpack documentation:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer contains links to the relevant information, but in case they become invalid or you are too lazy to look at them here is the config you need to add to your `craco.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 5000
  }
}
```

Note that devServer is a top level property in the config.

Comment: Any quick explanations as to why devServer is top-level instead of under `webpack: config`?

Comment: https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/devserver/